# What affects the acclimatization process?

Tags: hiking, mountaineering, high-altitude, acclimatization

We know we need "Climb High and Sleep low" to prevent Altitude Sickness.

Now the question is what can affect the acclimatization process?

Example:

- Bring luggage/bag/etc when climbing high. Will this affect acclimatization speed?
- Age
- Gender
- Weather

Comment: The question as it stands is way too broad, anything **can** influence acclimatization. If you narrow it down to what factors are commonly agreed upon to influence acclimatization it is still very broad, but maybe answerable (Charlie basically went into that direction).

Comment: As @imsodin already said you'll have to provide some circumstances to narrow down your question. The answer to this question would be a whole book :)

Comment: isn't it better if create new question again, because if i narrow down question, then the answer and  title will be not valid anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bringing gear up when climbing high won't really affect the rate.

There is a possibility that a higher pressure system could increase the amount of oxygen, but true acclimatization takes [long enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effects_of_high_altitude_on_humans#Acclimatization_to_altitude) that it probably won't matter.

According to the [Altitude Research Center](http://www.altituderesearch.org/hypoxia/altitude-hypoxia-explained)

> Women are more susceptible to acute mountain sickness but less so to
>   pulmonary edema.

There is also a study that show a link between [obesity and altitude sickness](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2003/08/030820072542.htm).

Apparently [people over 50](http://cozine.com/2006-february/a-benefit-of-aging/) are at a lower risk of altitude sickness.

On the other hand fit young men can be at a higher risk, because of how they climb i.e. [ascending too fast](http://www.climbmountkilimanjaro.com/on-the-mountain/safe-trekking/altitude-sickness/how-to-avoid-ams/).

There are also [drugs](http://www.webmd.com/drugs/2/drug-6753/diamox-oral/details) that can be used to prevent and treat it.

Beyond all of this, it can vary from person to person, so you will want to watch yourself for any symptoms and learn how your body reacts to altitude. Personally, I have never had anything worse than insomnia from altitude, but other people on the same trip had different reactions.

Comment: FYI, the link to the Altitude Research Center is broken.  It's currently still available through the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20161110112742/http://www.altituderesearch.org/hypoxia/altitude-hypoxia-explained) though

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what Charlie Brumbaugh said and will not repeat it, but will offer an perspective on what the individual can do.

*The single most effective thing you can do to improve your acclimatization rate is to get in good aerobic shape before starting your trip.*

Ability to acclimatize varies enormously among individuals, and, for an individual, ability to acclimatize can depend on the altitude.  Some people are fine at modest elevations (say, 14,000 feet and lower) and then just top out.

Ability to acclimatize will *eventually* lessen with age, but at what age the decline becomes noticeable will again vary enormously with the individual.  And, again, staying aerobically fit will postpone that decline.  Moreover, if you take several yearly trips, you may find your ease of acclimatization actually increases with the years (for awhile.)

As for weather, naturally you will be able to move more briskly if it is not too hot, but this would be true at sea level.  As long as you are pushing yourself but not exhausting yourself -- *and staying hydrated* -- you will acclimatize.

Statistics won't tell you anything about *yourself* at altitude or anywhere else.

Comment: i think its not just about me, if i know what can affect acclimatization proces i think i can prevent the other(on my team) to get alltitude illness.

Comment: Can you name any studies supporting the claim that good aerobic shape lessens the risk of AMS in any way? AFAIK there were several studies not finding any link between the two.