# How best to condition oneself to do day hikes at an altitude peaking at 6,000 to 8,000 ft?

Tags: hiking, acclimatization

I have hiked in years past up to 12,000 ft but normally topped out around 8,000 ft when doing day hikes. 
Problem is that I'm in my 60's, haven't hiked in 3 years and live at an altitude that tops out below 1,000 ft .  I'd liked to feel comfortable enough that I could do a 6 mile round trip day hike topping out at 8,000 ft.

My question is how best to condition myself and get back in shape to do these kind of hikes?
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I recently did a trail race on the Continental Divide (crested at 13,200) (I live at 5,300). I used Accli-mate, a powdered drink mix, and got great results. Was it a placebo? Maybe, but I'm happy with the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Older people better tolerate high altitude. For that altitude you don't need to do any special trainings\preparation. It would be enough to do any sport activity like running swimming or bicycle. The more sports you do the more comfortable you will be during your hike.

Comment: I did not know that older people better tolerate high altitude.  That is interesting and took me by surprise.  I can't swim and the doc wants to save my knees (lol) so no running.  I guess I'll use the bike.  Thx.

Comment: Do you have a source for your claim that older people tolerate high altitudes better than young people?

Comment: @Erik see my answer here https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/14739/what-affects-the-acclimatization-process/14740#14740

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh thanks for the links. That was interesting. I don't know if wives will be convinced that their husbands want to bring their Viagra on a trip in case of altitude sickness.... :)

Comment: @Erik, no I don't have any good source. I thought that is well known fact. At least it's written on russian wiki