# Are there any studies showing that being in good aerobic shape will lessen the risk of altitude sickness?

Tags: acclimatization

This [answer](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/14739/what-affects-the-acclimatization-process/14740#answer-14741) mentions,

> The single most effective thing you can do to improve your acclimatization rate is to get in good aerobic shape before starting your trip.

It seems plausible that being in good aerobic shape would help one acclimatize, are there there any studies to back this up?

Comment: I think things are usually mixed up: Fitness does not prevent altitude sickness, but it obviously can be a requirement for successful and efficient acclimatisation. One method for acclimatisation is to climb high and sleep low - if you aren't fit enough to go high, that won't work.

Comment: You've misinterpreted the statement I think. Being in-shape doesn't decrease your risk of altitude sickness, it increases your rate of acclimatization. Meaning you will acclimatize faster than the average person.

Comment: @ShemSeger Do you have any studies to back that up?

Comment: I was merely pointing out the discrepancy between the asks in your question title versus in the body of your question. There's a difference between getting altitude sickness and acclimatizing. You can get altitude sickness easier if you aren't properly acclimatized. Anyone can acclimatize to a degree, but the statement in in question claims you can acclimatize faster if you're in better shape to begin with.

Comment: @ShemSeger But wouldn't acclimatizing faster mean that you have a lower chance of getting altitude sickness?

Comment: Only *after* you've acclimatized. It's a process. For example: Everyone who climbs Everest acclimatizes for almost a month before their summit bid, but people who are from higher elevations can shave a couple weeks off of that and head up to base camp earlier, whereas people from sea level typically spend 2 weeks in Katmandu before heading up to base camp.

Comment: Please stop conflating lack of acclimatization with alititude sickness.  Lack of acclimatization means that one has less energy and stamina than one would at a lower elevation.  Lack of stamina is not necessarily the same thing as being sick.  (For example, I'm feeling tired right now because of jet lag, not sickness.)

Comment: @ab2 No lack of acclimatization means that the body has yet to adjust to being at high altitude and until one acclimatizes, one will be at an increased risk of altitude sickness. What you seem to be thinking of is the reduced performance by people who are operating with less oxygen than they are used to.

Comment: @Charlie Brumbaugh Yes, that is what I mean, and that is what lack of acclimatization means.  People who lack acc. are obviously more susceptible to altitude sickness, but they do not necessarily get even mild altitude sickness.  Let's keep the two concepts separate.  People who have not yet acclimatized go slower, stop more frequently and cannot comfortably accomplish as much as they usually do, but they do not necessarily get headaches, sleep poorly, have a reduced appetite, feel nauseated or contract HAPE or HACE.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No - the studies show that aerobic fitness has no protective effect. This is from the Institute for Altitude Medicine:

> MYTH - PHYSICAL FITNESS PROTECTS AGAINST ALTITUDE SICKNESS.
>
> Physical fitness offers no protection from altitude illness. In fact, many young fit athletes drive themselves too hard at altitude prior to acclimatizing thinking they can push through the discomfort. They ignore signs of altitude illness thinking it can't affect them because they are fit and healthy. Everyone, regardless of fitness, is susceptible to AMS.

[Source](http://www.altitudemedicine.org/myths-about-altitude/)

Anecdotally, I remember a season in Chamonix with my climbing partner - we hadn't done much training before the trip but spent a few days acclimatising. Then we were joined by a couple of friends who were superbly fit, having recently run fast times in the London Marathon. We blew them off the hill for the first two or three days till they caught up with their acclimatisation. There are no shorcuts.